# Excel Script - Split list into 3 sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I run a report of email addresses every month and split the list into 3 different sheets within the same workbook depending on the domain of each address.  Each row contains about 5 columns of data, so the whole row must be moved to the next sheet.

It would look something like this:

**If column B contains "@aaaaaa.com" keep row on sheet 1.**

**If column B contains "@bbbbbb.com" move whole row to sheet 2.**

**If column B contains "@cccccc.com" move whole row to sheet 3.**
Check next row

In the end I need 3 separate sheets that contain a list of each of the three domain email addresses.  I do this by hand now and going through 400+ rows is too tedious when I now there is a better way.  Any help on this would be much appreciated!

Comment: At least use the macro recorder first and post that code here, then ask for help with it...

Comment: Yes you could do it using VBA, but now you just want us to do the work for you. This is not a nice approach. Here in StackOverflow we want to help those who show their efforts. You should post your code first!

Comment: What have you done so far in VBA? Maybe we can help.

Comment: Thanks WhiteCat.  This tells me at least that I can use VBA to do this.  I'll do some research and appearanlty write my own code.  I'll run it by you when I have something.

Comment: you could also do this with a pivot & pivot filters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be enough to get you started.

```
Sub split()

Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws3 As Worksheet
Dim domain As String
Dim a As String
Dim b As String
Dim c As String

Set ws1 = Worksheets(1)
Set ws2 = Worksheets(2)
Set ws3 = Worksheets(3)

a = "aaaaaa.com"
b = "bbbbbb.com"
c = "cccccc.com"

lastrow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

ws1.Select

For i = 1 To lastrow

    domain = Right(Cells(i, 2), 10)

    If domain = b Then

        Rows(i).Copy
        ws2.Cells(i, 1).PasteSpecial

    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: You response was by far the most helpful!  This is a great starting point.